# Eclipse Java KeyEvent.VK_LEFT (NOT WORKING)

Tags: keycode

This is some code that should create a oval that can be controlled via arrow keys.

I have done lots of research but I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.

I am using Eclipse Mars with the Java language. Here is my code.

```
package com.game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Game extends Applet implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    public int x,y;
    public boolean up,down,left,right;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;

    public void init(){
        setSize(854,480);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(854,480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        this.addKeyListener(new Game());
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("X: " + x);
            System.out.println("Y: " + y);
            if(left == true){
                x--;
            }
            if(right == true){
                x++;
            }

            if(up == true){
                y--;
            }
            if(down == true){
                y++;
            }
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
            System.out.println("Left key pressed");
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
            System.out.println("Right key pressed");
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;
            System.out.println("Left key pressed");
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;
            System.out.println("Left key pressed");
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 854, 480);
        d.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }

}
```

When running this code, pressing arrow keys is not doing anything.